# jQuery AJAX reload specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following code, as part of a code to add some value to a database.

After executing the `$.ajax` succesfully, I want a specific div (with class '`lijst`') to be reloaded with the refreshed data.

```
$.ajax({
  url: \"frontend/inc/functions/add_selectie.php\",
  type: \"POST\",
  data: ({ 'p_id' : p_id, 'v_id' : v_id, 'pd_id' : pd_id }),
  cache: false,
  success: function()
  {
    $(\".lijst\").hide().fadeIn('slow');
  }
});
```

However, with this solution, only the div is refreshed, not the actual PHP variables that are specified in there. When I refresh my browser manually, the values are updated.

How can I refresh the div and also update the variables?

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery.ajax documentation, the function signature of "success".

> Type: Function( PlainObject **data**, String textStatus, jqXHR
>   jqXHR ) A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function
>   gets passed three arguments: **The data returned from the server** ...

So in other words:

```
success: function(data) {
  $(".lijst").html(data).hide().fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the PHP variables specified in the html are worked at the sever part. PHP variables in the html have replaced by the string of there value when it is ready to be sent to the browser. And your ajax request will cause PHP to update database. So when you have sent the request and then refresh the page, PHP will replace the varables in the html again.

According to this above, your ajax request and the server repsonse are not aware of the PHP variables's existence. So you must update the content yourself.

Maybe you will do something like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    $(".lijst").hide();
    $(".title").html(data.title);         // $(".title") may be a tag that surround a PHP variable
    $(".content").html(data.content);     // the same as $(".title")
    $(".lijst").fadeIn('slow');
}
```